# error al crear una base de datos

Tags: postgresql

[image]

Buenas eh intentado crear una base de datos pero cada vez que intento conectarme me sale este error

Comment: El error indica claramenteindica  que algun parámetro de la conexión es inválido. ¿Tú servidor de base de datos esta ejecutandose? ¿los parametros que usas son los correctos?

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes tener PostgreSQL instalado en tu PC, despues inicialicar por primera vez la base de datos en un directorio que no exista para que sea creado por Postgres:

```
> pg_ctl.exe -D ".\nuevo_vvacio\" initdb
Los archivos de este cluster serán de propiedad del usuario «Io».
Este usuario también debe ser quien ejecute el proceso servidor.

El cluster será inicializado con configuración regional «Spanish_Mexico.1252».
La codificación por omisión ha sido por lo tanto definida a «WIN1252».
La configuración de búsqueda en texto ha sido definida a «spanish».

Las sumas de verificación en páginas de datos han sido desactivadas.

creando el directorio ./nuevo_vvacio ... hecho
creando subdirectorios ... hecho
seleccionando el valor para max_connections ... 100
seleccionando el valor para shared_buffers ... 128MB
seleccionando implementación de memoria compartida dinámica ...windows
creando archivos de configuración ... hecho
ejecutando script de inicio (bootstrap) ... hecho
realizando inicialización post-bootstrap ... hecho
sincronizando los datos a disco ... hecho

ATENCIÓN: activando autentificación «trust» para conexiones locales.
Puede cambiar esto editando pg_hba.conf o usando el parámetro -A,
o --auth-local y --auth-host la próxima vez que ejecute initdb.

Completado. Ahora puede iniciar el servidor de bases de datos usando:

    "C:/Users/Io/PortableApps/pgsql/bin\pg_ctl" -D "./nuevo_vvacio" -l archivo_de_log start
```

Enseguida inicias la instancia del servicor como se indica:

```
> pg_ctl.exe -D "./nuevo_vvacio"
```

Necesitas después un "database profile" con la siguiente información sobre tu servidor PostgresQL: dirección del host, puerto, usuario y contraseña.

[image: Dialo de wizard para creqr un "Database Profile"]

Puedes entrar a este wizard si seleccionas en el menu "Database" > "Create Database Profiles ..." o utilizando la combinación de teclas Ctrl+Shift+P

Comment: Ya intente hacer eso y tampoco funciono me sale el mismo error

Comment: ¿Qué datos estas poniendo en los campos Host, Port number y User name?

Comment: Host: localhost ,  Port number : 5432 ,  User name : postgres

Comment: Lo mas probable es que necesites entonces tener un servidor creado y ejecutandose, me serviría saber cual es la versión de PostgreSQL que instalaste

Comment: Ah tengo la version 18.12.0.1

Comment: Var la respuesta editada para los pasos que faltan antes de crear el "Database profile"